# Compare two versions of a document

Tags: version-control, architecture

How would you implement a version control system for a single file ?

The point of this system would be to highlight what changed between two versions of the same file (pretty much what git does).

Instead of storing the whole document, it's usually better to store the first version of the file and  every "push" would just store every modification. However, how can we spot an insertion, a modification, a deletion or even a mix of both efficiently ?

Answer (score 0):

There are version control systems which handle single files.  One can use many modern version control systems, such as Git, and simply store a single file, but one tool which works on independent files is [RCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_Control_System).

Most version control systems adopt either a series-of-snapshots approach, like Git, or a changeset approach, like Arch and RCS.  Notably, RCS uses *reverse deltas*; that is, only the latest version of a file is stored in full, and each older revision is stored as a change against its subsequent revision.

In either case, the way to detect changes is a [diff algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff).  There's the standard Myers approach, plus modifications like the patience and histogram algorithms.  They are all based around finding the longest common subsequence (possibly with some modifications) and then representing the non-common parts as insertions, removals, or, in some cases, modifications.

The idea of a "modification" in a diff is hard to quantify because whether we think of a single-line change as logically the insertion of one line and the removal of another or a modification to the line depends on whether the human reading the line thinks it constitutes a substantive change.  Because gauging human opinion is difficult for software, some diff generation approaches, like the unified diff, always produce additions and removals, and others, like the context diff, always consider this a modification.